# Reverse for 'design' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:['builder\/design\/(?P<template_id>[^/]+)\/(?P<template_type>[^/]+)\\/$']

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to use a builder where users can choose layout. But getting the following error -

```
>         NoReverseMatch at /builder/
>     
>     Reverse for 'design' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['builder\\/design\\/(?P<template_id>[^/]+)\\/(?P<template_type>[^/]+)\\/$']
```

I am really lost. I saw many similar questions. I tried the solutions offered in those but could not resolve the issue. I have checked the variable names, I have checked the template, The context I am sending out has all the elements.

My view is -

```
def index(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    templates = Template.objects.filter(Q(user_id=user_id) | Q(user_id=1), builder=2).order_by('id')
    layouts = templates.filter(layout=1, user_id=1).order_by('title')
    others = templates.filter(layout=2, user_id=1).order_by('id')
    owns = templates.filter(user_id=user_id).order_by('id')
    context = {'title': 'Template Builder', 'layouts': layouts, 'others': others, 'owns': owns}
    return render(request, 'builder/index.html', context)


@login_required(login_url='signin')
def design(request, template_id, template_type):
    user_id = request.user.id
    path = MEDIA_ROOT + '/builderjs/' + str(user_id) + '/tmp/'
    create_builder_directory(path)
    json_template_data = get_template_data(user_id)
    if 'new_builder_create' not in request.session:
        request.session['new_builder_create'] = {template_id: 1}
        saving_builder_content_to_temporary(user_id, None)
    else:
        visit = request.session['new_builder_create']
        if template_id not in visit.keys():
            visit[template_id] = 1
        else:
           visit[template_id] = visit[template_id] + 1
        request.session['new_builder_create'] = visit

    print(request.session['new_builder_create'])

   context = {'title': 'Template Builder', 'template_id': template_id, 'template_type': template_type,
           'json_template_data': json_template_data}
   return render(request, 'builder/design.html', context)
```

urls.py -

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='builder'),
    path('design/<str:template_id>/<str:template_type>/', views.design, name='design'),]
```

template for builder is -

```
    <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        {% for layout in layouts %}
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-30">
                            <div class="card">
                                <a target="_blank" type="button" href="{% url 'design' layout.id 'layouts' %}">
{#                                    <img width="100%" height="100%" class="_1xvs1"#}
{#                                         src="/media/builderjs/1/templates/{{ layout.id }}/thumb.png"#}
{#                                         title="{{ layout.title }}" alt="{{ layout.title }}">#}
                                    {{ layout.icon|safe }}
                                </a>
                                <div class="p-15">
                                    <a target="_blank" type="button" href="{% url 'design' layout.id 'layouts' %}"
                                       class="btn btn-outline btn-block btn-warning">{{ layout.title }}</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card roundangel mb-30">
                <div id="others" class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">
                        <span class="icon icon-sm"><i class="fs-20 fw-500 fa fa-filter"></i></span>
                        <strong>Preset&nbsp;</strong>Templates
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        {% for layout in others %}
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-30">
                            <div class="card">
                                <a target="_blank" type="button" href="{% url 'design' layout.id 'other' %}">
                                    <img width="100%" height="100%" class="_1xvs1"
                                         src="/media/builderjs/1/templates/{{ layout.id }}/thumb.png"
                                         title="{{ layout.title }}" alt="{{ layout.title }}">
                                </a>
                                <div class="p-15">
                                    <a target="_blank" type="button" href="{% url 'design' layout.id 'other' %}"
                                       class="btn btn-outline btn-block btn-warning">{{ layout.title }}</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card roundangel mb-30">
                <div id="owns" class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="card-title">
                        <span class="icon icon-sm"><i class="fs-20 fw-500 fa fa-filter"></i></span>
                        <strong>Your Own&nbsp;</strong>Templates
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        {% for layout in owns %}
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-30">
                            <div class="card">
                                <a target="_blank" type="button" href="{% url 'design' layout.id 'other' %}">
                                    {% check_thumb_exist_tag layout.user_id layout.id as thumb %}
                                    {% if thumb %}
                                        <img width="100%" height="100%" class="_1xvs1 own-thumb"
                                             src="{{ thumb }}"
                                             title="{{ layout.title }}" alt="{{ layout.title }}">
                                    {% else %}
                                        <img width="100%" height="100%" class="_1xvs1"
                                             src="{% static 'assets/vendor/builderjs/assets/image/default_thumb.png' %}"
                                             title="{{ layout.title }}" alt="{{ layout.title }}">
                                    {% endif %}
                                </a>
                                <div class="p-15">
                                    <a target="_blank" type="button" href="{% url 'design' layout.id 'other' %}"
                                       class="btn btn-outline btn-block btn-warning">{{ layout.title }}</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Thank you good people.

Comment: Hmm, this is strange, it looks like you're doing everything right. Is there a chance there's another call to `url 'design' ` that doesn't specify the parameters? At which exact point the error is being thrown?

Comment: @MaximKukhtenkov the error is being thrown whenever i am trying to access the 127.0.0.1/builder page. The index is the view in this case.

Comment: I see you have `def index()` function in views.py, but no `def design()` - did you define the "design" view?

Comment: Yes, I have defined the design function in views.py. I am adding the codes